# artifactory OSS self-hosted authentication using SAML/Azure AD

Tags: azure, artifactory, open-source, saml

Is it possible to authenticate Artifactory OSS (self-hosted) with Azure AD/SAML? Right now we use local Active Directory, but are thinking of deprecating local AD in favor of Azure AD, and moving most authentication to Azure AD/SAML. I understand the other versions of Artifactory can do this, but I can't definitively find if the self hosted OSS version does. If it does not, it may drive us to one of the pay models.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SAML SSO](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/SAML+SSO) is not supported in the OSS version of Artifactory. In the link provided, you might find useful information on the top right of the page for JFrog Subscriptions that support the feature (relevant to all features).

Also, you can check the [Pricing](https://jfrog.com/pricing/#hosted) page for the different features included in each subscription. You should find the SAML SSO feature under the "Pro" subscription level and "Platform Security".

I hope this clarifies more.

Comment: As I suspected, thanks.